# addClass('x') always return false...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question with JS and I would like to know why it happens.

I am using .addClass('x') and it always return false when it isn't truth.

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" id="botonChangeAlert" class="btn-warning"> btn-?  </a>
```

JS:

```
$("#botonChangeAlert").click(ejecutarChangeAlert);

function ejecutarChangeAlert() {
    //$("botonChangeAlert").hasClass("btn-warning");
    alert($("botonChangeAlert").hasClass("btn-warning"));
    //alert($("botonChangeAlert").hasClass("btn-alert"));
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean `hasClass` (not `addClass`) always returns *false*:

You are using the wrong selector. You use `$("botonChangeAlert")` but want to select an element by the attribute `id="botonChangeAlert"`. To do that, you need to prepend the selector with `#` as in `$("#botonChangeAlert")`.